# Change Bootstrap navbar logo image when navbar changes state on hover/scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap template that flips the navbar between white and transparent on hover and on scrolling.

I have a logo image in the Navbar like so.

```
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
   <img width="100px" src="/assets/logo.png" />
</a>
```

I'd like to be able to load a different logo when the navbar is transparent compared to when it is white.

I've seen a number of different solutions for doing this outside of Bootstrap but there must be a simpler way to achieve this using Bootstrap classes.

I need to have both image urls in the html so was thinking of something along the lines of...

```
 <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
    <img class="logo-white" width="100px" src="/assets/logo-white.png" />
    <img class="logo-dark" width="100px" src="/assets/logo.png" />
 </a>
```

But then how can I do something with those new classes based on the set bootstrap classes?

Comment: u can use [srcset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with *just* Bootstrap classes but you could use CSS to toggle the `display` attribute of the images when the parent navbar is in a hover state:

```css
/* initial states */
.logo-off {
  display: block;
}

.logo-on {
  display: none;
}

/* hover states */
.navbar:hover .logo-off {
  display: none;
}

.navbar:hover .logo-on {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jacobwhatnow/pen/jOMJMoo).

Comment: I had just worked out how to do this with regards to the scrolling, your reply has helped me with the hover, thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to Jacob, my full CSS solution is as follows...

```
/* initial states */
.logo-light {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .logo-dark {
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* hover states */
  .navbar:hover .logo-light {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .navbar:hover .logo-dark {
    display: block;
  }

/* scroll states */
.navbar.fixed-top .logo-light{
    display: none;
}

.navbar.fixed-top .logo-dark{
    display: block;
}
```